# Is there any ipv6 bootnode?

Tags: go-ethereum, bootnodes, ipv6

Roughly speaking, the most popular Ethereum client: geth determines its external IP by inspecting the endpoint from ENRequest's PONG message. [The local IP address which receives most statements is considered to be the external IP](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/p2p/netutil/iptrack.go). Since [all the bootnodes are IPv4 peers](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/params/bootnodes.go), IPv6 nodes are unable to join P2P network in practice.

Is there any reliable IPv6 bootnode?

Answer (score 0):

Try to answer my own question here.

According to [ethernode](https://ethernodes.org/client/geth), 78% Ethereum mainnet clients are using geth. During geth's initializing phase, it will [randomly communicate with 3 bootnodes](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/p2p/discover/table.go#L299). Since all the bootnodes run on IPv4, it's impossible for IPv6 node to join the network.

Much like a democracy society, the majority wins. My limited guess is today's IPv6 is not mature enough to meet the latency and availability needs of a global-scale decentralized P2P network.